# Calculating km² represented by same pixel value in a 1km² resolution raster?

Tags: qgis

From a raster resolution of 1km² we want to calculate the area that represents each pixel of the same color. The calculation must be done in QGIS.

[image]

Update : what parameters should I insert here:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot indicates that you're using a continuous raster that is simply being symbolized as discrete classes. Consider running **Reclassify by table** to cement those classes into the data, converting the different ranges into coded integers.

With a reclassified raster, you can easily run the **Raster layer unique values report** tool to obtain the information you're looking for:

[image: reclassified raster]

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| Value | Pixel count |    Area (ft²)     |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
|     1 |        1396 |  3454412666071.69 |
|     2 |       14581 |  36080795905437.9 |
|     3 |       26366 | 65242868448170.61 |
|     4 |         505 | 1249626358428.512 |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
```

**Update**: Here is what my reclassification table looked like. Also, I used the **Range boundaries** type `min < value <= max` and checked the box for `Use no data when no range matches value`.

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| Min | Max | Value |
+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 |   5 |     1 |
|   5 |   8 |     2 |
|   8 |  12 |     3 |
|  12 |  20 |     4 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: What values are put in the reclassification table? because I get an error when I insert it and I put the maximum and minimum for each color group on the map

Comment: I've added what my reclassification table looked like.

Comment: Parámetros de entrada:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'INPUT_RASTER' : 'E:/modelar ramon/OK Modelos OK/50 IPSL-CM5A-LR/ip26bi50/Recortada/Modelada/a_median.asc', 'NODATA_FOR_MISSING' : False, 'NO_DATA' : -9999, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'RANGE_BOUNDARIES' : 0, 'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'TABLE' : [2.756-07,0.250,None,0.251,0.374,None,0.375,0.497,None,0.498,0.955,None] }

Valor inválido para el mínimo: 2.756-07
La ejecución falló después de 0.40 segundos

Cargando las capas resultantes
Algoritmo 'Reclasificar por tabla' finalizado

Comment: How you set the values?

Comment: You should be able to just type into that cell.

Comment: Do you have a drive or mega to teach you the raster and tell me what are the values that I must put for the reclassification? i need this urgently please help me

Comment: I need help witjçh this please

Comment: I dont have idea